# Find the volume bounded by $4z=16-x^2-y^2$ and the plane $z=0$ using double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I solved the question using double integral: 
$$\int_{-4}^{4}\int_{-\sqrt{(16-x^2)}}^{\sqrt{(16-x^2)}}
\frac{16-x^2-y^2}{4}dydx$$

the answer I'm getting is $32\pi$ but my book answer is $16\pi$. 
What am I doing wrong?[image]

Comment: The "answers at the back of the book" are often wrong.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown so am i correct? answer would be 32pi..!!

Comment: Yes, you could perhaps sell the book, because the answer is $32\pi$. Also the https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference mathjax tutorial is very well written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get
$$\frac{2\pi}4\int_0^4 r(16-r^2)\,dr=(64-32)\pi=32\pi.$$